# Which method is the most practical for this volume problem?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by

$$ y = \frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9}}, x = 4, y-axis $$

Rotated about the y-axis.

After drawing the graph, I wanted to simply take the integral in regards to y and do the disk method but then I looked at $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9}}$ and decided that there might be an easier way than that.

Am I able to simply use the shell method here instead?

Such that:

$$ 2 \pi \int_0^4 4 * \frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9}}$$

Pulling out the numbers up front:

$$ 24 \pi \int_0^4 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell method should be

$$
V = 2\pi \int_0^4 xf(x) \ \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Would the shell method work for this problem? Also, I thought it was $\int_0^4 2 \pi (width)(height) dx $. I thought the width of it was 4 (since thats where x stops and the height was the f(x) which is $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9}}$ ?

Comment: But the width is constantly changing, it is given by $x$. It should work.

Comment: I guess I didn't think of it like that. So it should read $2 \pi \int_0^4 \frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9}} $? Take the 3 out front and then integrate?

Comment: Sure! Try substitution.